# Format sdcard and read superblock issue

Tags: format, sd-card

I've tried to format my sd card with no luck so far. Everytime I put it in my card reader, Ubuntu throws back at me this error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/haunted/FC30-3DA9: Command-line `mount -t "vfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/haunted/FC30-3DA9"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/sdb1: can't read superblock
```

also I have installed gparted to see if it was detected at least, but apparently no. I can safely rule out a card reader issue: Windows 7 and the digital camera also have problems reading the memory card. Is there anything I can do?

**Edit** (dmsg output):

```
[  467.145226]  sdb: sdb1
[  468.618376] FAT-fs (sdb1): error, invalid access to FAT (entry 0x0d9025b8)
[  468.618381] FAT-fs (sdb1): Filesystem has been set read-only
[14525.007780] FAT-fs (sdb1): error, invalid access to FAT (entry 0x0d9025b8)
[14525.007784] FAT-fs (sdb1): Filesystem has been set read-only
[14528.686295] FAT-fs (sdb1): error, invalid access to FAT (entry 0x0d9025b8)
[14528.686304] FAT-fs (sdb1): Filesystem has been set read-only
[14532.642288] FAT-fs (sdb1): error, invalid access to FAT (entry 0x0d9025b8)
[14532.642297] FAT-fs (sdb1): Filesystem has been set read-only
[14549.438700]  sdb: sdb1
[14549.846281] FAT-fs (sdb1): error, invalid access to FAT (entry 0x0d9025b8)
[14549.846286] FAT-fs (sdb1): Filesystem has been set read-only
```

Comment: What's in `dmesg`?

Comment: @jippie added to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but since I found a simple solution which I didn't noticed anywhere during searching for one, it might help someone in the future:

I faced the same issue with two micro-SD cards today (which I usually mount via an adapter on the built-in card reader of my pc) and both failed. 
My first thought was that since both cards were working fine until yesterday, the adapter was "kaput", so I tried an external usb card reader which successfully mounted both (I also have to mention that both cards are formated as vfat).

I began to investigate what's wrong with the adapter or the built-in card reader and tried a lot of solutions I could think of and some that I found on the internet without success, and then I tried the unthinkable:

I inserted the card with the adapter's hard switch set to "read-only" and it mounted!
After that, I just unmounted, removed and reinserted the card with the hard switch set to read-write, and since then it works like a charm.